# Chrome on Android restarts when device docked in cradle

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome

In Android I understand that when there is a configuration change to the device like a screen orientation change or the device being docked that the default behaviour of an activity is to restart.

For the chrome browser this seems to be the case when a device is docked that has power.

We have an offline HTML5 application and so this causes major problems where our application is basically restarted when the device is docked and the user loses all their unsaved changes.

Is there anyway of stopping chrome restart when a device is docked?

For a cordova/phonegap application it looks like we can add a setting to the AndroidManifest.xml file to stop a restart of the cordova/phonegap application.